# Flex/Bison Calculator with both Floats and Integers

Tags: c

I am trying to implement a simple calculator (for operations +-*/) with unsigned floating point and integer numbers. First I have created a .h file which implements a linked hash table as my symbol table. The .h file hold the struct definitions and the function declaration that are implemented in my .c file. Using flex i am able to get the tokens given by the user and using bison i define the grammar. Everything works for the integer numbers, but i am having trouble implementing the floating point numbers. I don't know how to write the grammar to properly distinguish which operation should take place. All the codes are attached below.

symtab.h

```
#define SIZE 10
#define MAXTOKENLEN 40
#define UNDEF 0
#define INT_TYPE 1
#define REAL_TYPE 2

typedef struct node 
{
    char name[100];
    int par_type;
    int ival;
    float fval;
    struct node *next;
}var;

typedef struct hash 
{
    var *head;
    int count;
}hash;

static hash *hashTable = NULL;
var *newNode(char n[], int t, int i, float f);
void Insert(char n[], int t, int i, float f);
void Print();
var *Search(char n[]);
void Change(char n[], int t, int i, float f);
```

symtab.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "symtab.h"

var *newNode(char n[], int t, int i, float f) 
{ 
    var *temp =  (var *)malloc(sizeof(var));

        strcpy(temp->name, n);
        temp->par_type = t;
    temp->ival = i;
    temp->fval = f;
        temp->next = NULL;

        return temp; 
};

void Insert(char n[], int t, int i, float f) 
{
    int hashIndex, h = 0;
    var *newnode = newNode(n, t, i, f);

    /* Finding the sum of the ASCII values of each character of the variable's name*/
    for (int c = 0; n[c] != '\0'; c++)
        h = (h + (unsigned char)n[c]);

    /* hashIndex is equal to the sum of the ASCII value of the variable's name mod the number of elements in the table*/    
    hashIndex = h % SIZE;

    /* head of list for the bucket with index "hashIndex" */
    if (!hashTable[hashIndex].head) 
    {
        hashTable[hashIndex].head = newnode;
        hashTable[hashIndex].count = 1;
        return;
    }

    // adding new node to the list 
    newnode->next = (hashTable[hashIndex].head);

    // update the head of the list and no of nodes in the current bucket
    hashTable[hashIndex].head = newnode;
    hashTable[hashIndex].count++;

    return;
};

void Print() 
{
    var *myNode;
    int i;

    printf("Name\tType\tINTEGER\tFLOAT\n");
    printf("------------------------------------------\n");

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
    {
            if (hashTable[i].count == 0)
                continue;

        myNode = hashTable[i].head;
            if (!myNode)
                continue;

            while (myNode != NULL) 
        {
                printf("%s\t", myNode->name);
            if(myNode->par_type == 1)
                printf("int\t");
            else if(myNode->par_type == 2)
                printf("float\t");
            else printf("undef\t");
            printf("%d\t%.2f\n", myNode->ival, myNode->fval);
                myNode = myNode->next;
            }
    }

    return;
};

var *Search(char n[]) //1
{
        int hashIndex, h = 0, flag = 0;
        var *temp = NULL;       

    for (int i = 0; n[i] != '\0'; i++)
        h = (h + (unsigned char)n[i]);

    hashIndex = h % SIZE;

    temp = hashTable[hashIndex].head;
    if (!temp) {
        printf("Search element unavailable in hash table\n");
        return temp;
    }

    while (temp != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(temp->name, n) == 0){
            flag = 1;
                break;
        }

            temp = temp->next;
    }

    if (!flag)
        printf("Search element unavailable in hash table\n");

    return temp;
}

void Change(char n[], int t, int i, float f) //2
{
    int hashIndex, h = 0, flag = 0;
        var *temp;      

        /* Finding the sum of the ASCII values of each character of the variable's name*/
    for (int i = 0; n[i] != '\0'; i++)
        h = (h + (unsigned char)n[i]);

    /* hashIndex is equal to the sum of the ASCII values of the variable's name mod the number of elements in the table*/    
    hashIndex = h % SIZE;

    temp = hashTable[hashIndex].head;
    if (!temp) 
    {
        Insert(n, t, i, f);
        return;
    }

    while (temp != NULL) 
    {
        if (strcmp(temp->name, n) == 0){
        if(temp->par_type == 1)
            temp->ival = i;
        else if(temp->par_type == 2)
            temp->fval = f;

            flag = 1;
            break;
        }

        temp = temp->next;
    }

    if (!flag)
        printf("Search element unavailable in hash table\n");

        return;
};
```

calc.l

```
%{
    #include "symtab.h" 
    #include "calc.tab.h"
    #include <string.h>
    void yyerror (char *s);
    int yylex();
%}

%%
"\n"                {return NEWLINE;}
"print"             {return print;}
"exit"              {return exit_command;}
[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z]|[0-9])*   { strcpy(yylval.name, yytext); return identifier; }
[0-9]+              {yylval.ival = atoi(yytext); return int_number;}
[ \t]               ;
[-+*/=;]            {return yytext[0];}
.               {ECHO; yyerror ("unexpected character");}

%%

int yywrap (void) {return 1;}
```

calc.y

```
%{
    void yyerror (char *s);
    int yylex();

    #include "symtab.c"
    #include <stdio.h>     /* C declarations used in actions */
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
%}

/* Yacc definitions */
%union  {
        char name[100];
        int par_type;
        int ival;
        float fval;
    }         
%start  line
%token  print
%token  exit_command
%token  NEWLINE
%token  <ival> int_number
%token  <name> identifier
%type   <ival> int_line int_exp int_term
%type   <name> assignment

%%

/* descriptions of expected inputs     corresponding actions (in C) */

line:           int_line
            ;
int_line:       assignment NEWLINE          {;}
            | exit_command NEWLINE          {Print(); exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);}
            | print int_exp NEWLINE         {printf("Printing %d\n", $2);}
            | int_line assignment NEWLINE       {;}
            | int_line print int_exp NEWLINE    {printf("Printing %d\n", $3);}
            | int_line exit_command NEWLINE     {Print(); exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);}
                ;
assignment:         identifier '=' int_exp          {Change($1, 1, $3, 0.0);}
            ;
int_exp:        int_term                        {$$ = $1;}
                | int_exp '+' int_term          {$$ = $1 + $3;}
                | int_exp '-' int_term          {$$ = $1 - $3;}
            | int_exp '*' int_term          {$$ = $1 * $3;}
            | int_exp '/' int_term          {$$ = $1 / $3;}
                ;
int_term:       int_number              {$$ = $1;} 
            | identifier                {$$ = Search($1)->ival;}
            ; 
%%                     /* C code */

int main (void) {
    hashTable = (hash *) calloc(SIZE, sizeof(hash));
    return yyparse ( );
}

void yyerror (char *s) {fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);}
```

Comment: Aside: can you at least use `double` for floating point? Even a basic calculator works to 8 decimal digits, better than the antiquated `float` (although `float`has its place).

Comment: i could swap float with double, but the problem still remains, how will i distinguish between and double and int?